# function for elements of the array multiples of the minimum element

Tags: c++

When I run the following only the large numbers come out but, the numbers for "Multiples of the minimum elements" doesn't show.

I can't see what's wrong with the code yet. Advice appreciated.

```
int A[15];

void fill(int arr[], int n, int left, int right)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[i] = rand() % (right - left + 1) + left;
}

void output(int arr[], int n, int w)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(w) << arr[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
}

int findMinElem(int arr[], int n)   
{ 
    int minelem = arr[0];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] % minelem == 0) minelem = arr[i] ;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int main()
{
    int n = 15; 
    fill(A, n, 0, 50);
    output(A ,n , 15);

    if (findMinElem(A, n ))
        cout << "Multiples of the minimum elements =\n";
    else 
        cout << "No multiples of the minimum element elements\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `arr[0]` is the minimum element?

Comment: `return true` isn't inside the `if`, so it will always happen the first time through the loop.

Comment: @Barmar, Why not just write those two things as answers?

Comment: Thank you . Yes i am not sure how to declare the minimum element i was try to put "0" insted of arr[0] and but still dont work. And about "return true" , teacher learn us to do it in this way and i am not sure if its correct or not .

Comment: @mihail.mgu Are you sure, that you didn't misunderstand something that was said by your teacher?

Comment: Yes the mistake of not understanding most of things it is on me , but my teacher doesn't like to say alot about programing ,and when i asking something most of the times i didn't get an answer , may be because he is very old and he dont like to do this any more i am not sure about that.

Comment: You need to say what the specific expected results are. You're filling an array with 50 numbers. Not sure why you're calling them left and right, then you're performing modulo arithmetic against the first element. It doesn't make a lot of sense to me. We can't help you if we don't understand the requirements clearly. You need to figure out how to clear up the question quickly or it's headed for closure.

Comment: Unless the array is sorted, to get the minimum element you have to go through the entire array first, checking each element to see if it's smaller than the minimum so far. Once you've done that, you can go through the array again, checking whether any element is a multiple of that minimum. Make sure you exclude the element itself. `return true` is fine, but you have to do it in the appropriate situation, when you've actually determined that the condition has been met.

Comment: Thank you! My post description was change , i think becouse of bad english... well there is a 3 function : First one is - function to fill the elements of the array with random numbers in the interval [left and right]; . Second - function to print the array elements of the screen; and Third - Function to find the number of elements of the array multiples of the minimum element . The first and second are ok , but third not working it is syntactically okey but semantically not at all.

Comment: Bramer thank you sir , but i never make this befor and i dont understand the syntax of the C++ very well yet i will try to do something to get it work.Thank you!